# embedded sql in C

Tags: sql, c, db2, embedded-sql

I've been attempting to write embedded SQL statements for DB2 that ultimately gets compiled in C.

I couldn't find a tutorial or manual on the embedded SQL syntax for C for reference. One case I would like to do is to insert data into a table. I know most embedded sql statements need the initalizer `EXEC SQL`, but that's the extent of my knowledge generally. I'm doing this for an assignment and would appreciate if there are more information regarding this or solution.

Example of a statement to query the database:

```
EXEC SQL SELECT SNAME, AGE into :sname, :sage
    FROM ONE.SAILOR
    WHERE sid = :sid;
```

I like to see what statement allows me to INSERT into the database. I've tried something like the following, but it doesn't work.

```
 EXEC SQL INSERT ....
```

Comment: Actually, I finally figured out I was missing INTO, thus it should be EXEC SQL INSERT INTO ...

whoops.

Answer (score 2):

See IBM's [Embedded SQL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.embed.doc/doc/t0007158.htm) manual.

Embedded SQL is largely the same no matter what the host language is.

Answer (score 2):

The four dots aren't syntactically valid :-D

The reliable way is the same as with any other INSERT statement: list the columns and the values.

```
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO SomeTable(Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(:hv1, :hv2, :hv3);
```

Here, the :hv1, :hv2 and :hv3 represent three host variables of types appropriate to the columns in the table.  Note that the table could contain other columns than these three as long as those columns have a default specified or accept NULL (which is really just a default default in this case).  The unreliable way does not list the columns:

```
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES(:hv1, :hv2, :hv3);
```

Now you are dependent on getting the sequence right, and you must provide a value for each column -- there cannot be extra columns in SomeTable.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using [sqllite](http://www.sqlite.org).  Besides the good [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html) for C++, SQLlist might be a nice thing to have because you can unit-test your code without being dependent on DB2 and it's really easy add with your code.